# Lightweight PDF viewer to navigate through files in a folder

Tags: windows, pdf, pdf-viewer

I have a rather large folder containing many PDF files. Opening each and every file from Explorer seems too tedious.

**Requirements**

- Lightweight PDF viewer

  There is no need to offer advanced options.
- The ability to navigate in the current folder in alphabetical order by a keyboard shortcut.
- Works on Windows 8.1
- **Bonus:** Rescale each PDF to fit the viewer's window size.

For example, IrfanView and [Windows Photo Viewer](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/view-and-use-your-pictures-in-windows-photo-viewer) do have this feature.

---

I have already tried opening Foxit Reader with multiple PDF documents as tabs. Navigating would then work by hitting <kbd>Ctrl+W</kbd> to close the current tab and thereby switching to the next tab. However, it seems that Foxit Reader doesn't preserve the alphabetical order in some cases.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## [Sumatra PDF](http://www.sumatrapdfreader.org/free-pdf-reader.html)

> Sumatra PDF is a free PDF, eBook (ePub, Mobi), XPS, DjVu, CHM, Comic Book (CBZ and CBR) reader for Windows
>
> Sumatra PDF is powerful, small, portable and starts up very fast.

[image]

✅ Lightweight
✅ <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> to scroll through files
✅ Work with Windows
✅ Rescale each PDF to fit the viewer's window size

[image]

Comment: @NicolasRaoul it will. I understand the intention and motivation, but in this case, I feel like it's nitpicking

Comment: +1 Thanks now that's a great answer! :-) The problem if we are not strict is that answerers will just post links without saying what requirements the product fits or does not fit, leaving it to every one of the 1300 visitors to figure out by clicking the link of each answer.

Comment: Nice, I was looking for such a PDF Viewer, but I already had Sumatra installed, just didn't know about that shortcut.

Comment: It might be worth adding the command to make SummartraPDF into your pdf previewer for explorer & outlook, etc: https://forum.sumatrapdfreader.org/t/outlook-preview/700/7 discusses.