# PDF viewer that quickly displays thumbnails of all PDF files in a folder

Tags: windows, gratis, pdf, pdf-viewer

Many people are familiar with common image viewers like IrfanView or xnView.  They have the capability to display thumbnails of all the images in a folder, and then allow you to click on any thumbnail to quickly view that file.

I am looking for a similar application, but for PDF documents.  I want to quickly see thumbnails for all the PDF files in a folder, and then be able to click on a thumbnail to quickly view it.

The thumbnails must be large enough to get a general idea of the contents of the PDF file.  Thumbnails that are too small will not work.

Fast speed is very important.  I need to look through thousands of PDF files.

The **thumbnail functionality** is the key.  I'm good if it has to use an external application to view the PDF in full size.  Or, if it includes its own full-size viewer, that is fine as well.

The application must work on [windows](/questions/tagged/windows).  It must be [gratis](/questions/tagged/gratis).  I prefer it to be [portable](/questions/tagged/portable), but that's not a requirement.  I strongly prefer that it does not install any hooks into other applications, such as Windows Explorer.

Similar, but different question: [Lightweight PDF viewer to navigate through files in a folder](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/14886/lightweight-pdf-viewer-to-navigate-through-files-in-a-folder)