# HEIF/HEIC viewer to quickly browse HEIF/HEIC files in a folder

Tags: windows-7, image-viewer

I am looking for an [HEIF/HEIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Efficiency_Image_File_Format) viewer for Microsoft Windows 7 that can  quickly browse HEIF/HEIC files in a folder (like Windows Photo Viewer does for JPG files).

Any license and price is fine. I know that I could instead first batch convert the HEIF/HEIC files to JPG but I would prefer not to have to do it.

---

What I have found so far:

- I am aware that [Windows Insider Build 17123 Supports The High Efficiency Image File Format (HEIF)](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/microsoft/windows-insider-build-17123-supports-the-high-efficiency-image-file-format-heif/) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20180526190306/https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/microsoft/windows-insider-build-17123-supports-the-high-efficiency-image-file-format-heif/)) but my version of my Microsoft Windows is older than that.
- Adobe Bridge [doesn't support preview for HEIF/HEIC files](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2378129#) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20180526191107/https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2378129)).
- Related question, for PDF files: [Lightweight PDF viewer to navigate through files in a folder](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/14886/903))

Answer (score 2):

You can use  [XnView](https://www.xnview.com/en/xnview/#downloads):

- freeware ("no adware, no spyware") for private or educational use (including non-profit organizations).
- has a portable version
- has HEIF support: Extract http://www.xnview.com/download/plugins/heif_x32.zip in `Plugins` folder.
- works on Microsoft Windows 7, 10 and 11

On my computer, it takes around one second to preview each HEIC picture. Also, it uses 0.5G of RAM.

[image]

[image]

It also crashes from time to time:

[image]

Comment: Works on Windows 11 too